# all value from nested json is not comiing in list

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to parse nested json and populating in listview but only 0th index data is coming on listview while the length of array is 3.

```
{
  "entries": [{
      "Doctor_Criteria_2": "Physician",
      "Status": "Completed",
      "Comment": "Testing",
      "Timeline_For_Reporting": "1 month",
      "Doctor_Criteria_1": "10",
      "Speciality": "1",
      "Faculty_No": "2",
      "stars": [
        "Sumit",
        "Kumar",
        "Saini"
      ],
      "Event_Id": "1503209071",
      "Speaker_No": "2",
      "End_Date_Time": "2017-08-25T10:00",
      "Budget_Allocation": "2017-08-26T10:00",
      "No_Of_Doctors_Assign": "Barbiturates",
      "Doctor_Assignment": "Physician",
      "Actual_Budget": "15000",
      "Start_Date_Time": "Enthuse",
      "Event_Name": "Med_Vision",
      "Product_List": "10000",
      "Assign_Team_Name": "0",
      "Modular_No": "3"
    },
    {
      "Doctor_Criteria_2": "Physician",
      "Status": "Completed",
      "Comment": "Hello",
      "Timeline_For_Reporting": "1 month",
      "Doctor_Criteria_1": "10",
      "Speciality": "1",
      "Faculty_No": "2",
      "stars": [
        "Sumit",
        "Kumar",
        "Saini"
      ],
      "Event_Id": "1503237005",
      "Speaker_No": "2",
      "End_Date_Time": "2017-08-26T10:00",
      "Budget_Allocation": "2017-08-27T10:00",
      "No_Of_Doctors_Assign": "Barbiturates",
      "Doctor_Assignment": "Physician",
      "Actual_Budget": "15000",
      "Start_Date_Time": "Enthuse",
      "Event_Name": "Med_Vision",
      "Product_List": "10000",
      "Assign_Team_Name": "0",
      "Modular_No": "3"
    },
    {
      "Doctor_Criteria_2": "Physician",
      "Status": "Approved",
      "Comment": "",
      "Timeline_For_Reporting": "1 month",
      "Doctor_Criteria_1": "10",
      "Speciality": "1",
      "Faculty_No": "2",
      "stars": [
        "Sumit",
        "Kumar",
        "Saini"
      ],
      "Event_Id": "1503288226",
      "Speaker_No": "2",
      "End_Date_Time": "2017-08-30T10:00",
      "Budget_Allocation": "2017-08-31T10:00",
      "No_Of_Doctors_Assign": "Barbiturates",
      "Doctor_Assignment": "Physician",
      "Actual_Budget": null,
      "Start_Date_Time": "Enthuse",
      "Event_Name": "Anukriti",
      "Product_List": "10000",
      "Assign_Team_Name": "0",
      "Modular_No": "3"
    }
  ],
}
```

I am using the code below to parse the data

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){      
//    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
//        mode = 'search/movie?query=',
//        movieName = '&query='+encodeURI('Batman'),        
//        key = '&api_key=5fbddf6b517048e25bc3ac1bbeafb919';    
    var url = 'https://usv.mybluemix.net/USV/Json.jsp';

    $.ajax({
//        url: url + mode + key + movieName ,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
             $('#work-in-progress').fadeOut(0);
            ajax.parseJSON(result);


        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');

            document.getElementById("internet_access").innerHTML="No internet access";
        }
    });         
});
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){      
    $('#movie-data').empty();

    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.Event_Id == movieInfo.id) {
   // here i want to display stars value in drop down in Doctor_Name
          if(row.stars && row.stars.length > 0)
          {

            for(var i =0;i<row.stars.length;i++)
              {
                 $('#movie-data').append('<li data-identifier="'+row.stars[i]+'" data-store-name="'+row.stars[i]+'"><input type="checkbox"/>'+row.stars[i]+'</li>');
              }

        }
       // document.getElementById("user").value =USER_NAME;

         // document.getElementById("Store_name").value = row.Event_Name;

          //  $("#Doctor_Name").select2("val", "");
           $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');    
        }
    });    
});

$(document).on('vclick', '#movie-list li a', function(){  
    movieInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
});

var movieInfo = {
    id : null,
    result : null
}

var ajax = {  
    parseJSON:function(result){  
        movieInfo.result = result.entries;
        // here I am populating JSON on listview (#movie-list) and then I am going in details of that data after clicking on that list.
        $.each(result.entries, function(i, row) {
            if (row.Status != "Completed") {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="'  + row.Event_Id + '">' +'<h3>' + row.Event_Name + '</h3><p1>' + row.Event_Id + '</p1><br><p2>' + row.Start_Date_Time + '</p2><br><p2> '+row.End_Date_Time + '</p2><p>'+row.Status +'</p></a></li>');
        }});
        $('#movie-list').listview('refresh').trigger("create");;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something? It doens't seem like your're even using the json data in the success callback: `ajax.parseJSON(result); ` is the last line of that callback.
Edit. Sorry, I saw `ajax` was some custom object you had. Though it was jQuery.

Comment: @jonahe, look at the end of OP code, this is where `ajax.pareJSON` is declared

Comment: Only one element is coming up since you test if `Status` is different from `Completed`, and only one element matches this condition...

Comment: https://usv.mybluemix.net/USV/Json.jsp
here is dummy json
in below code am appending json value
$('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="'

Comment: ohhh... got it.. silly mistake ..

Comment: Thanks for making me understand